# Customer_Eav db schema version is not properly set

Tags: magento2, composer, database-schema

I am using **Magento 2.2.5** and getting this error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Customer_Eav db schema version: defined in codebase - 1.0.3, currently installed - 1.0.5
Customer_Eav db data version: defined in codebase - 1.0.3, currently installed - 1.0.5
```

I run "**composer install**", but no error shows, even upgrade command also run successfully.

Comment: try to check with schema version in your database table "setup_module" with module.xml of a specific module.

Comment: `Customer_Eav` does not look like a core module. Is it something you installed from somewhere else?

Comment: no marius.. i am not installed anything else

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this error by following way:

Update in your database:

```
UPDATE `table_prfix_setup_module` 
 SET schema_version="1.0.5", data_version="1.0.5"
 WHERE  module="Customer_Eav";
```

Comment: in setup_module , it will update version of only module, but Customer_eav is not module i think

Comment: can you check in your database is there any table exists like "Customer_Eav"?

Comment: no, only customer_eav is not , but customer_eav_attribute is there